# How to factor polynomials with complex coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Factor completely the polynomials

$$p(x)=5ix^4-(9+2i)x^3+7x+6-i$$
and
$$q(x)=9x^5-x^3+7x+6$$

First, I tried to use the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra but it did not work out. ThenI tried plugging in values like $x=-i,i-1$ and nothing worked. Can I have some hints on how to proceed?

Comment: You can try $\pm1$ or $\pm(6-i)$ divided by $\pm1$, $\pm5$, $\pm i$, or $\pm5i$. But it seems to be these are not going to work. Next step go to the [ugly formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Ferrari.27s_solution)!?

Comment: $q(x)$, for example, is irreducible over the rational numbers. And for most irreducible quintics, there simply isn't a formula for the roots. So I'm not sure what final form you're shooting for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both polynomials are irreducible not merely over **Q**, but over $\mathbb Q[i]$ as well. Furthermore, the roots of the latter are [inexpressible in radicals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Finding_roots_of_a_quintic_equation), and those of the former involve hideous expressions.